# Is there any difference among "mindestens", "zumindest", and "wenigstens"?

Tags: difference

I would like to know if there is any difference between "mindestens", "zumindest", and "wenigstens". I have asked two Germans that, and one said that there is no difference, whereas the other said there is. I am confused. Is this possible difference up to interpretation? Is it just a change in nuance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Mindestens" tends to be used with countable elements of the same type, or at least with something quantifiable:

> Wir brauchen mindestens drei Kartoffeln.
> We need at least three potatoes.

> Füllen Sie die Flasche bis mindestens zur Markierung.
> Fill the bottle up, at least to the marking.

"Zumindest" tends to be used with unquantifiable things:

> Du hättest zumindest anrufen können.
> You could at least have given me a call.

> Zumindest in meiner Stadt ist mir kein solcher Fall bekannt.
> At least in my city, I'm not aware of such a case.

This isn't a clear-cut distinction, though, so you may well find examples where the terms are used the other way around.

Regarding "wenigstens", this is in my experience a matter of perspective. You might say that with "mindestens" and "zumindest", you look at things from a lower amount and express that it could be more. With "wenigstens", you look at things from a higher amount and express that it could go as low as this. But this distinction is quite subtle and may well be blurred in everyday speech.